# jpa sql get limit 1 of all rows with unique value in another column

Tags: sql, postgresql, jpa

Goal is to have a sql (or better jpa) way to get all rows with highest c1 for all unique entries in c2.

TableA:

```
id | c1 | c2 | c3
1  | 9  | 3  | 1
2  | 8  | 3  | 3
3  | 7  | 2  | 4
4  | 6  | 3  | 6
5  | 5  | 2  | 3
6  | 4  | 3  | 2
7  | 3  | 2  | 1
```

Expected result:

```
1  | 9  | 3  | 1
3  | 7  | 2  | 4
```

```
SELECT c2, MAX(c1) FROM TableA GROUP BY c2;
```

that query works, but for some reason, group by gets extremly slow when there are more than 100 million rows (count of distinct c2 is about 3).

explain psql output:

```
 Finalize GroupAggregate  (cost=1592599.23..1592600.50 rows=5 width=16)
   Group Key: c2
   ->  Gather Merge  (cost=1592599.23..1592600.40 rows=10 width=16)
         Workers Planned: 2
         ->  Sort  (cost=1591599.21..1591599.22 rows=5 width=16)
               Sort Key: c2
               ->  Partial HashAggregate  (cost=1591599.10..1591599.15 rows=5 width=16)
                     Group Key: c2
                     ->  Parallel Seq Scan on TableA  (cost=0.00..1347845.07 rows=48750807 width=16)
 JIT:
   Functions: 7
   Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true
(12 rows)
```

there are indexes on basically everything.

`select c2, c1 from Table A where c2=3 order by c1 desc limit 1;`

this always returns instantly (because there is an index on (c2, c1 desc)).

main goal is to have the same output as:

```
SELECT a.c3 
FROM TableA a
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT c2, MAX(c1)
    FROM TableA
    GROUP BY c2
) b ON a.c2 = b.c2 AND a.c1 = b.c1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little hard to follow, but you should be able to use `distinct on`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (c2) c2, c1
FROM TableA a
ORDER BY c2, c1 DESC;
```

This should make use of an index on `(c2, c1 DESC)`.

You can also select `c3` in this query (and any other columns).  It is unclear if that is sufficient for the final version.

Comment: that seems perfect, but although explain says it uses the index, its still really slow. I think because it still groups all c1-entries together and orders them unnecessaryly and then returns the first of that group.

Comment: @Vertago . . . It does take time to read an index with 100 million rows.

Comment: but the db should know where the first entry is. the index should be ordered by c1 desc, so asking for the max-entry or first entry should be instant, as it is with "select c2, c1 from Table A where c2=3 order by c1 desc limit 1;". there must be a way to group all 100 million entries is not necessary

Comment: my current workaround is to query how many distinct c2-values there are and then firing that many queries with limit 1. which is way faster than letting the database group it... I hope there is a better way.